# Text-only Description field in Google News RSS Feeds

Tags: java, android

Google news url
http://news.google.com/?output=rss
it will return google rss news in the rss  tag with html tags.
i want only textual description only.
please help me...

Comment: What you have tried & what problem you are facing?

Comment: http://news.google.com/?output=rss it will return description like <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;"><tr><td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif">.... like bt i want only texual descritpiom

Comment: Do you know how to parse a data from web api, if not then see some useful links here: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/ ,http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html , http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: Robi sir m parsing xml ...bt i want only detail not want html ...coz indise html it include all information like title , image ,n all

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the XML. There is a detailed tutorial on how to use the Android XML pull parser over at the docs: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. Have a look.

Once you parse the data, store it in a list. Then, pass that list to an adapter so that you can create a list / grid of views that will be populated based on whatever data you wish to display from the feeds.

**Edit:**
Have a look at [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html). It says:

> Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any
>   img tags in the HTML will display as a generic replacement image
>   which your program can then go through and replace with real images.

Seems like it will suit your need :)

Comment: Thanks for reply .. m parse the xml ... bt my probs is inside <description> tag there is HTML ... how to handle this .... coz i need only textual description not html

Comment: @RajeshPatil `fromHtml()` doesnt suit your need ?

Comment: Html.fromHtml() m using this for convert to texual ... sir i want descrition in textual format only no need for html format... coz only i want only news detail no need for all thing inside the description

Comment: Then [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is your guy because it lets you **scrape and parse HTML from a URL, file, or string** :)

Answer (score 0):

I parse the HTML description from the XML using regex like this:

```
Pattern patronGoogle = Pattern.compile("(<\\/font><br><font\\b|(?!^)\\G)[^>]*?\\b(size)=\"-1\">([>]?)([^<]*)\\3");
Matcher mGoogle = patronGoogle.matcher(description);
if (mGoogle.find()) {
    System.out.println("Only the Text of the Google RSS: " + mGoogle.group(4));
}
```

You can check it here: https://regex101.com/r/dDfSbe/1